# How can I convert text to paths with pdflatex?

Tags: fonts

Is there any way to convert text to paths? I tried to use Inkscape, but it 
has some troubles with reading a PDF file.

The PDF is produced by `pdflatex` (I can't use `dvips`) with the **beamer** class and the **beamerposter** package.

Basically, I understand that Type1 fonts should be enough, however people in our print office require paths instead of text.

Comment: You can also use `dvips` with beamer!

Comment: no, beamerposter has some problems with dvips and don't produce correct file

Comment: well, I don't know why, hovewer all tips were too much complicated or don't work... In fact, different printer solved my problem... Anyway, my question should be deleted...

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
pdftops -level3 myfile.pdf myfile.ps
```

(note `pdftops` not `pdf2ps`) and then use ghostscript to convert back to pdf with a command something like:

```
gswin32c -q -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dNOPAUSE -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile=myfile-curves.pdf -c "/show { true charpath currentpoint /jy exch def /jx exch def fill jx jy moveto} bind def /ashow {exch pop exch /j_ax exch def show /j_ax {0} def } bind def /widthshow { show pop pop pop} bind def /awidthshow {ashow pop pop pop} bind def" -f myfile.ps
```

Comment: This doesn't work any more, certainly not in gs9.14.

Comment: @yo' and exactly how does it fail?

Answer (score 2):

Works also with package `beamerposter`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{News}{}
\pscharpath{\RM Japan won}\par\pause
\pscharpath[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!70]{\RM the World}\par\pause
\pscharpath[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!70]{\RM Cup}\par\pause
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative with less possibilities for filling is to use an outline font  like Biolinum:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontface\Outline{Linux Biolinum Outline O} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{News}{}
\fontsize{40}{42}\selectfont\Outline
Japan won\par\pause
the World\par\pause
Cup\par\pause
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This needs a `lualatex` or `xelatex` run!

[image]

Comment: so, I have to use \pscharpath before each textline and redeclare all fonts?

Comment: yes, but you can also use an outline font, see my edit.

Comment: could you, please, put somewhere on the web final pdf? I'm not sure if it is exactly what I need

Comment: Why don't you run the above examples??

Comment: 'cause something is wrong with beamerposter and I'd like to know, whether this is what I need before I start solving that troubles...

Comment: http://perce.de/temp/latex6.pdf shows the first solution in landscape format

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding,  it is Women's World Cup not Men's World Cup.

Comment: Am **I** stupid, or this answers a completely different question?!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to convert the entire document into outlines, in this case you can use `pdf2ps` utility to convert the PDF to outlined PS file, and you can then use `ps2pdf` to convert it back to PDF (both utilities from Ghostscript).

```
$ pdffonts test.pdf 
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
PEUCZM+Amiri-Regular                 CID TrueType      yes yes yes     18  0
$ pdf2ps test.pdf 
$ ps2pdf test.ps
$ pdffonts test.pdf 
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
---
```

---

Comment: colors are different, the letter "l" is bold???!!! and one figure looks like after some compression :(

Comment: This does _not_ work with a recent (9.05) GhostScript. Comments [here](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-postscript/162017-convert-fonts-outlines-free.html) indicate that it was a misfeature if it once worked.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

You can use Foxit PhantomPDF (see [here](https://kb.foxit.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040240852-How-to-convert-text-to-shape-in-a-PDF-file-)):

1. Select the text you want to convert (Tip: Use Edit Object > Text to only select text)
2. Right click and press the "Convert to shape object" button at the bottom.

## Solution 2

Adobe Acrobat also can do this (see [this](https://mrserge.lv/2022/how-to-convert-fonts-to-outlines-in-pdf-with-adobe-acrobat/) blog post):

1. When you have opened the document you want to work with, look at the right side, and in the **Tool** panel click **More Tools** button.
2. Now from here type in the **Search bar** *Preflight* and click on **Preflight** next to **Print Production**.
3. In the now open Window, select **Profiles**.
4. Make sure you have pressed the green bars button next to the Search field
5. Enter *Convert fonts* into the field.
6. Select **any** of the **Convert fonts to outlines** profiles and press the **Analyze and fix** button.

## Solution 3

Alternatively if you don't want to use these proprietary tools you can use the [mat2](https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2) metadata removal tool, which will also convert all text to paths.

1. After installation, call it with `mat2 /path/to/file.pdf`.
2. The now created file `/path/to/file.cleaned.pdf` should have all text converted to paths.

## Solution 4

Another way is to convert each page the document to an individual SVG file and then reconvert and recombine those (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855026/convert-pdf-text-into-outlines) StackOverflow post).

### Convert pages to SVG:

```
import os, math

import cairo
import poppler

def convert(inputname, base=None):
    '''Converts a multi-page PDF to multiple SVG files.

    :param inputname: Name of the PDF to be converted
    :param base: Base name for the SVG files (optional)
    '''
    if base is None:
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(inputname))

    # Convert the input file name to an URI to please poppler
    uri = 'file://' + os.path.abspath(inputname)

    pdffile = poppler.document_new_from_file(uri, None)

    pages = pdffile.get_n_pages()

    # Prefix the output template with zeros so that ordering is preserved
    # (page 10 after page 09)
    output_template = ''.join([
        base,
        '_',
        '%0',
        str(math.ceil(math.log10(pages))),
        'd',
        '.svg'
    ])

    # Iterate over all pages
    for nthpage in range(pages):
        page = pdffile.get_page(nthpage)

        # Output file name based on template
        outputname = output_template % (nthpage + 1)

        # Get the page dimensions
        width, height = page.get_size()

        # Open the SVG file to write on
        surface = cairo.SVGSurface(outputname, width, height)
        context = cairo.Context(surface)

        # Now we finally can render the PDF to SVG
        page.render_for_printing(context)
        context.show_page()

        # Free some memory
        surface.finish()
```

### Assembling the SVGs into a PDF:

```
import rsvg
import cairo

def convert_merge(inputfiles, outputname):
    # We have to create a PDF surface and inform a size. The size is
    # irrelevant, though, as we will define the sizes of each page
    # individually.
    outputsurface = cairo.PDFSurface(outputname, 1, 1)
    outputcontext = cairo.Context(outputsurface)

    for inputfile in inputfiles:
        # Open the SVG
        svg = rsvg.Handle(file=inputfile)

        # Set the size of the page itself
        outputsurface.set_size(svg.props.width, svg.props.height)

        # Draw on the PDF
        svg.render_cairo(outputcontext)

        # Finish the page and start a new one
        outputcontext.show_page()

    # Free some memory
    outputsurface.finish()
```