# How to convert text in a PDF file from fonts/text to outlines?

Tags: fonts, pdf, pdftex, ghostscript

I have PDF graphic in which I would like to have fonts removed. All other properties of the file should remain (such as size, etc). The output file should be in PDF as well. The text itself should be converted to outlines.

Can I do it at the moment of including the PDF figure in pdftex document? Or can I perhaps use a magic ghostscript command?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23407/how-can-i-convert-text-to-paths-with-pdflatex

Comment: Well, because this is a figure and not a page, the output after pdf2ps and then ps2pdf is a full-page document. The size has been lost...

Comment: Do you mean that you have a lot of white space around the figure? So the final step can be to use pdfcrop (included in TeXLive, don't know in MikTeX).

Comment: Brilliant! That does what I wanted. I will update the question with an answer.

Comment: Rather than answering your question within the question itself, you should add a separate answer.

Answer (score 23):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798374/3399377), you should use the following command for the new (9.15+) ghostscript

***nix**

`gs -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o vectorized_file.pdf file.pdf`

**Win**

`gswin32 -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o vectorized_file.pdf file.pdf`

Comment: As of Feburary 7 2017, this was the only correct solution on this page (with a version of gs at least 9.15).

Answer (score 15):

In my case (pdftops 0.18.4, GPL Ghostscript 9.05) the resulting PDF following the above answer still contained the fonts and the text was not converted to curves.  However, the answer I found at [this Malaysian LaTeX User Group site](http://latex-my.blogspot.de/2012/01/text-to-path-conversion-with.html) worked for me.  This is the script I used:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "x$1" = "x" -o "x$2" = "x" ]; then
    echo Usage: `basename "$0"` "<input.pdf>" "<output.pdf>" >&2
    exit 1
fi

gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=- -q -dbatch \
   -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET "$1" -c quit | ps2pdf - "$2"
```

Of course, a `pdfcrop` step can still be added if you need it.

If this gives you an error use -sDEVICE ps2write

Comment: Excellent! None of the answers in the linked questions worked. Your script does work.

Comment: Thank you! If the OP is available, I would certainly nominate this post for being the appropriate and most effective answer.

Comment: Hmm... On Ubuntu 14.04 with gs 9.10, using `-sDEVICE=ps2write` with the final `ps2pdf` conversion does not seem to keep the text as paths. I will look for some solutions.

Comment: Looks like using `pdf2svg` with a SVG to PDF conversion tool (perhaps with Inkscape) does the job! From a [Launchpad Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/295564/comments/6).

Comment: @eacousineau It does, but `pdf2svg` is obviously unable to use float numbers properly, because my graphics got destroyed by the utility. Anyways, this answer is out-dated, it doesn't work in gs9+.

Comment: @eacousineau This worked perfectly for me with the same setup (Ubuntu 14.04, gs 9.10, `-sDEVICE=ps2write` with the final `ps2pdf` conversion)

Comment: @yo' It does work for me with gs 9.10.

Answer (score 5):

(Originally posted as part of question by OP ronszon)

The solution to the problem was conversion from PDF to PS, PS to PDF and cropping final PDF file.

```
pdftops myfile.pdf
ps2pdf myfile.ps
pdfcrop myfile.pdf
```

Comment: I don't know what you think that should do, but it does _not_ convert the fonts to outlines (at least not with gs 9.05).

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is using `pdf2svg`, as indicated here: [Launchpad Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/295564/comments/6).
In Ubuntu, you can install it as `sudo apt-get install pdf2svg`

My overarching goal in reading this post was to be able to edit the raw paths of the PDF in Inkscape, so this accomplishes my goal quite well.

EDIT:

As a succinct command, you can add the following command:

```
pdf-text-to-path() { name=${1%.[Pp][Dd][Ff]}; pdf2svg $1 $name.raw.svg; inkscape --export-pdf=$name.raw.pdf $name.raw.svg; }
```

The command `pdf-text-to-path $name.pdf` will generate `$name.raw.svg` and then use `inkscape` to convert the SVG to PDF in `$name.raw.pdf`. (Note: You will need Inkscape, which is admittedly bulky. `convert` seems to rasterize the image.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I don't see how this produces a PDF file? As well, it would be nice to make the answer self-contained, i.e., to show how exactly can `pdf2svg` be used to accomplish the goal of the question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I've made the corresponding adjustments.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Just: **(1)** Yes, `convert` is from ImageMagick which is a raster image processor. **(2)** `inkscape` knows to modify the dimensions of the PDF file if this is done, just so slightly, yet it can change the output significantly.

Answer (score 1):

The `-sDEVICE=pswrite` output driver in Ghostscript has been [deprecated since 12/15/2010](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/History9.htm). In Ghostscript versions >= 9.09, use `ps2write` or `eps2write`.

Comment: The question is 3 years old. You should tell that gs could have changed also options etc.  Does it (I do not know)?  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This does not convert the fonts, it keeps them there! And FWIW, it has always been the case for gs9+.