# Missing text when using dvisvgm in conjunction with an eps file

Tags: pdftex, eps, dvisvgm

When running `dvisvgm` to convert a `dvi` file to `svg` I'm loosing the text information which is part of the `eps` file.

When running `pdflatex` the output is correct.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{figureA}
\end{document}
```

Below the output:

[image: Output of pdflatex and dvisvgm]

Attached the `eps` file which is included:
https://app-factory.ethz.ch/images/figureA.eps

Edit:
I ended up with the following workaround:

```
ps2pdf  -dEPSCrop  figureA.eps figureA.pdf
gs -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o v_figureA.pdf figureA.pdf
pdf2ps v_figureA.pdf figureA2.eps
```

This converts fonts in to outlines and I will used the vectorized eps file.

See here: [How to convert text in a PDF file from fonts/text to outlines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27327/how-to-convert-text-in-a-pdf-file-from-fonts-text-to-outlines)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I can confirm what you observe. How was the figureA.eps generated?

Comment: In the EPS file PS operator `xyshow` is used to trigger text output. dvisvgm doesn't support this operator yet. Sorry.

Comment: I just added support for PS operators `xshow`, `yshow`, and `xyshow` to dvisvgm. So, as of the next version, the missing text will appear in the generated SVG.