# Selectable text in called PDF

Tags: graphics

I used the \includegraphics to insert a PDF into my latex document. The PDF is called, but its text is selectable. What can I do to make its text unselectable?

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm},clip,scale=0.8]{Selectable.pdf}
    \caption{\small The Selectable Figure.}
    \label{fig.1}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a feature, not a bug :). You can include the graphic as a **PNG file** for example --> then the text is not selectable anymore.

Comment: although even with an image, these days it's trivial to select the region and ocr the original text so if the intention is to stop people accessing the text, then deleting the text is the only option

Comment: Sort of duplicate, containing a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27327/how-to-convert-text-in-a-pdf-file-from-fonts-text-to-outlines (i.e., convert the text to outlines before including the pdf).