# How to create handwriting practice sheets with descender guides

Tags: fonts

How can I modify the command in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96766/writing-practice-sheets-dotted-letters) to add a solid line at the descender height and make the baseline dotted?  I'd also like to be able to fill the page with guides and optionally add solid or outlined letters to one or more of the guides.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but anyone interested in handwriting will enjoy a visit to http://operina.com/  Note especially the PDF of Arrighi’s *Operina*.