# Arcing the center dots between factors to show repeated multiplication

Tags: symbols, accents

Consider the center dots to show repeated multiplication:

```
\[
x \cdot x \cdot x \cdots x.
\]
```

I want to use five dots instead of the three from the `\cdots` command, and I also want to have them subtly arced like on the path of part of a downward-opening parabola or something.

Does such a command already exist?  If not, is it possible to create such a command or achieve it on a one-off/as-needed basis?

pdfLaTeX user.

Comment: The purpose of this is visual.  I think it might add a touch of visual stimulation to my written explanations or illustrative examples to students.

Comment: Why not `$x \cdot x \cdot \ldots \cdot x$`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the horizontal spacing needs changing, that can be done with kerns.  If it is needed in smaller (script) mathstyles, let me know in a comment and I will revise my answer to provide them.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\repdots{\mathbin{{\cdot}\raisebox{.75pt}{$\cdot$}%
  \raisebox{1pt}{$\cdot$}\raisebox{.75pt}{$\cdot$}{\cdot}}}
\begin{document}
$x \cdot x \cdot x \cdots x.$

$x \cdot x \cdot x  \repdots x.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT to add extra \cdot kern (also supports smaller mathstyles)**

The value of `\dotkern` is used to space out the `\cdots`. The value `1\LMpt` (Local Math pt) is 1 pt in text and display styles, but proportionately smaller in the smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\newcommand\dotkern{\kern1\LMpt}
\newcommand\repdots{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{{\cdot}\dotkern%
  \raisebox{.75\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle\cdot$}\dotkern
  \raisebox{1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle\cdot$}\dotkern%
  \raisebox{.75\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle\cdot$}\dotkern{\cdot}}}}
\begin{document}
$x \cdot x \cdot x \cdots x.$

$x \cdot x \cdot x  \repdots x.$

$\scriptstyle x \cdot x \cdot x  \repdots x.$

$\scriptscriptstyle x \cdot x \cdot x  \repdots x.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To make it truly parabolic  change .7pt to .75 pt: `\newcommand\repdots{\mathbin{{\cdot}\raisebox{.75pt}{$\cdot$}\raisebox{1pt}{$\cdot$}\raisebox{.75pt}{$\cdot$}{\cdot}}}`

Comment: @Dan LOL :-)...I like the parabolic dots :-))))

Comment: Thanks, @Dan. If I had given it more thought, I should have known that.  Retired for 2 months and all my elementary skills evaporate!!

Comment: Perfect!  How to adjust the horizontal spacing so that it is the same as in ```\cdots``` or ever so slightly closer?

Comment: @UngarLinski Please see my **SUPPLEMENT**

Answer (score 4):

Steven's answer is excellent, but just for fun we can make a macro for arbitrary dots and curvature.

Use as follows: `\repdots{# dots}{max vertical displacement in pt}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\repdots[2]{\mathbin{\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{\FPeval\temp{(-((\n-1)/(#1-1))*((\n-1)/(#1-1)-1)*4*(#2))}\raisebox{\temp pt}{$\cdot$}}}}
\begin{document}
$x \repdots{5}{1} x \repdots{4}{-3} x \repdots{30}{6} x \repdots{7}{-2} x$\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer also this :-)...more parabolic.....

Comment: Now can we spell out my name in cursive with the dots?  :)

Comment: @UngarLinski Easier to do something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96766/writing-practice-sheets-dotted-letters to make letters.