# Hand-writing practice sheet- how to draw the lines and letters for tracing

Tags: english

Hi I want to recreate worksheets similar to this- for practicing writing. I am very unsure as how to go about it. I want to use the `exam` document class which is good for `\fillwithlines{}` command. However, I am not sure where to even begin. For example, how make the letter dotted, how to choose the width of the lines, how to choose the font for the letters and write them as shown here.

Can you please help!?

[image]

Comment: Related:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96766/14100

Answer (score 4):

Here is what what have so far with the help.

I am recreating a sheet like the above- letters from A to Z or any numbers so that kids are able to trace them when learning to write.

I tried to incorporate the code from the link but I am finding it extremely difficult. to add the dashed letters on top of the lines.

I don't really understand how to modify the suggested code to get the letters on the lines here.

```
\documentclass[20pt]{exam}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 11in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage{paracol}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{FullLinesColor}{RGB}{219,48,120} % color of the full lines  <<<<<<<<<<<
\definecolor{DottedLinesColor}{RGB}{50,120,220} % color of the dots <<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\Dotsep}{2pt}% dot separation <<<<<<
\newcommand{\Dotthickness}{0.3pt}% dot thickness <<<<<<
\newcommand{\LineThickness}{0.3pt}% full line thickness <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\LinesSepStretch}{1.5}% change the baseline stretch <<<<<

\newcommand{\nicelines}[1][12pt]{% \nicelines{<vertical block separation>}  
    \begin{spacing}{\LinesSepStretch}
    {\noindent\color{FullLinesColor}\rule{\linewidth}{\LineThickness}}
    {\color{DottedLinesColor}\linedotted{\linewidth}{\Dotthickness}}
    {\color{DottedLinesColor}\linedotted{\linewidth}{\Dotthickness}}
    {\vspace*{#1}\color{FullLinesColor}\rule{\linewidth}{\LineThickness}}
    \end{spacing}
}
\newcommand{\linedotted}[2]{\hbox to #1{\leaders\hbox to \Dotsep{\hss\bigpoint{#2}\hss}\hfill}} 
\newcommand{\bigpoint}[1]{\tikz\draw[DottedLinesColor,fill=DottedLinesColor] (0,0) circle (#1);}      
%******************************************************** 

\begin{document}

\subsection{The letter C}

\nicelines[24pt] 

\begin{paracol}{3}

\nicelines[24pt] 

Photo goes here. 

\switchcolumn

\nicelines[24pt] 

\nicelines[24pt] 

\nicelines[24pt] 

\switchcolumn

\nicelines[24pt] 

\nicelines[24pt] 

\nicelines[24pt] 

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a free (for noncommercial use) font called KG Primary [available for download here](https://www.makerstype.com/fonts/kg-primary-dots/).

Compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{KGPrimaryDotsLined}

\begin{document}

\Huge
The quick brown fox...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! Is there any way to change middle lines from 1 to 2 and make it similar to the above picture in my original question.